# Chart.js chart doesn't appear in JSF page using template

Tags: javascript, jsf

In this page, a command button must execute a JavaScript function which draws some charts from [`Google Charts`](https://developers.google.com/chart/) and [`Chart.js`](http://www.chartjs.org):

[`Chart.js`](http://www.chartjs.org) is loaded just after `h:form`, then [`Google Charts`](https://developers.google.com/chart/). Other JS code is after that.

The error displayed in JS console after clicking the button:

> **ReferenceError: execGoogleCharts is not defined**

Files:

template1.xhtml http://pastebin.com/iQrMimys

chartjs.xhtml http://pastebin.com/PFtkdnRX

radar-chart-script.js http://pastebin.com/3jXXaMES

RadarChartJsonServletMaximo.java http://pastebin.com/yvXa1dJe

The other servlets are almost the same, changing the parameter passed to `getValores(String tipo, int clienteId)` (getValues(String type, int clientId)) and some database parameters.

Comment: I removed the call to PrimeFaces' `RequestContext` and used jQuery's `.click`, now that error is gone, but charts does not appear and no error is shown in console.

Comment: Apparently, it's actually not loading some managed beans I used inside the JS functions called to create the charts. I'll check more deeply now.

Comment: It works only outside `ui:composition`.

Comment: Template's code: http://pastebin.com/iQrMimys